# Помогите исправить ошибку в коде, у меня не получается вывести функцию числом

Tags: javascript

```js
const root = document.getElementById('root');
function createBoxes(amount) {
  const basicSize = 30;
  const fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();
  for (let i = 0; i < amount; i++) {
    const size = basicSize + i * 10;
    const div = document.createElement('div');
    div.style.cssText = `width: ${size}px; height: ${size}px; background-color: rgba( ${random()} , ${random()} , ${random()} )`;
    fragment.appendChild(div);
  }
  root.appendChild(fragment);
}

function destroyBoxes() {
  root.textContent = '';
}

function random() {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
}
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
```

У меня ничего не выводит!
Нужно создать функцию createBoxes(num), которая принимает 1 параметр num - число.

Функция создает столько div, сколько указано в num и возвращает их в одном
  общем контейнере. После чего необходимо повесить результат работы функции
  в div с id="#root"

Каждый div:
    - Имеет случайный rgb цвет фона
    - Размеры самого первого div - 30px на 30px.
    - Каждый следующий div после первого, должен быть шире и выше предыдущего
      на 10px

Comment: Вы нигде не вызываете свою функцию `createBoxes()`. Если ее вызвать, то все работает

Comment: Не знаю что делаю не так уже вызвала функцию createBoxes() и у меня не работает?((

Comment: Все работает... В самом конце кода добавь    createBoxes(4)

Comment: сори действительно работает )))))

Answer (score 0):

```js
const root = document.getElementById('root');
function createBoxes(amount) {
  const basicSize = 30;
  const fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();
  for (let i = 0; i < amount; i++) {
    const size = basicSize + i * 10;
    const div = document.createElement('div');
    div.style.cssText = `width: ${size}px; height: ${size}px; background-color: rgba( ${random()} , ${random()} , ${random()} )`;
    fragment.appendChild(div);
  }
  root.appendChild(fragment);
}

function destroyBoxes() {
  root.textContent = '';
}

function random() {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
}
createBoxes(6)
```

```html
    <div id="root"></div>
```